# how to stop webpage click events from like firefox/chrome developer console inspector tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

**Question #1:**
I am working on a chrome extension where it requires an inspector like tool to let user hover on a webpage. And to show outline on hover on a DOM element. 
When user clicks on any element, I need to show a popup besides the element. 
But at the same time that elements click event must not execute. It is very similar to developer consoles inspector tool. Can you please help how to do this ?

**Question #2:**
Can you please suggest why Chrome developer console's inspector tool does not work in this case ?

**To reproduce:**
1. Go to https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQ377A-8vQAhUHQY8KHUHxCv0QFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.developers.google.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNF0eH059mv86nMIlRmfsf42kde-wA&bvm=bv.139782543,d.c2I
2. Click on "products & services" menu (3 horizontal lines icon) in left top. A slide menu will open.
3. Start developer console (click F12).
4. Select anything on this menu.

**Actual result:**  Side menu closes.

**Expected result:** Side menu should not have closed and developer console should have shown its html.

Comment: Where is the link you've linked to supposed to lead? All it does is open my Google Developer console page. And no, the expected result is that the side-menu closes.

Comment: Thanks GAntonie! If you select any DOM element using inspector tool, that elements events do not execute, for example, you go to any site say jira, click on one of the top menu items, it opens a submenu. Now use inspector tool to select a menu option in the submenu. You see, submenu will neither open nor it closes. I am asking how chrom extension would have done this ? And similarly it should have happened in question #2, but it is not since it is closing the side menu.

Comment: Right, I may have an answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

1. I got a solution to this. I created a div (of size 4x4 px). I move
   this div with the mouse move event.  I set the div coordinates so
   that mouse tip is exactly at the middle of the div.
2. Div background is kept transparent, so that it is not visible to
   users. So when user clicks on element, he is actually clicking on
   the div.
3. And inside the div mouse down event, I stop event propagation.
   Please let me know if anyone reading need any more pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You may have tried this already, but I'd suggest adding a click listener to any clickable items, by adding these lines:

```
$(document).click(function() {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Though because of the way things bubble up in the DOM, events attached to children *may* still fire, depending on the browser.

Comment: Yes, I had already tried that. Please review my answer, it is working fine in almost all cases. Thanks for your reply!